# Update one of the multiple component's props in Vue.js from outside

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Can't find a way to update a specific component's prop from outside of the component.

I have an `App.js` which loads all components in `.vue` format. What a basically do is I import a `counter.vue` inside the `App.js`, and want to modify one of the specific component's data.

Main file `App.js`:

```
Vue.component('counter', require('./components/Counter.vue'));

export const App = window.App = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    methods: {

    }
});
```

Here is a `Counter.vue` file:

```
<template>
    <span class="counter">{{ number }}</span>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['name', 'number'],
    };
</script>
```

In my HTML I have multiple `counter` instances:

```
<counter name="cnameA" number="10"></counter>
<counter name="cnameB" number="20"></counter>
<counter name="cnameC" number="30"></counter>
```

How to I increment a counter with name `cnameB` by 1 ?

I tried to use a [#watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) approach, but it's not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the number you want to increment to a data property, then increment that property:

```js
Vue.component('counter', {
  template: `<span class="counter">{{ number }}</span>`,
  props: ['name', 'number'],
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      foo: 20,
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <counter name="cnameA" number="10"></counter>
  <counter name="cnameB" :number="foo"></counter>
  <counter name="cnameC" number="30"></counter>

  <button @click="foo++">Increase Second Counter</button>
</div>
```